# COPY INTO from Snowflake in array of json

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a copy statement that unload from Snowflake to S3.

```
COPY INTO @MY_STAGE/path/my_filename FROM (
SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*) from my_table) 
FILE_FORMAT =(TYPE = JSON COMPRESSION = NONE)
OVERWRITE=TRUE;
```

Current result in `myfilename.json`:

```
  {
   "a": 123,
   "b": "def"
  }

  {
   "a": 456,
   "b": "ghi"
  }
```

Using `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT()` will produce in [ndjson](http://ndjson.org/) format. However, I want to save the file in array of json such as:

```
[ 
  {
   "a": 123,
   "b": "def"
  },
  {
   "a": 456,
   "b": "ghi"
  }
]
```

The data needs to be stored in one single file. I know I need to do something with `SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*) from my_table`, however I'm not sure how to transform this.

Comment: It is probably easier to just use something like Python to convert an ndjson to json, see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67736164/convert-ndjson-to-json-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ARRAY_AGG`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html) to achieve this:

```sql
COPY INTO @MY_STAGE/path/my_filename FROM (
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*)) from my_table) 
FILE_FORMAT =(TYPE = JSON COMPRESSION = NONE)
OVERWRITE=TRUE;
```

This function converts your record set into an array. Since [Snowflake arrays](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html#array) are basically JSON arrays, the array returned by `ARRAY_AGG` can be written directly into the JSON file.

Unfortunately, `ARRAY_AGG` has a limitation of being able to hold only 16 MB of data. If your dataset is larger than this, it's unfortunately [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65905095/3738870) to write all of it into a file in your desired format.

Comment: This might not work and you might get: **Result array of ARRAYAGG is too large**

Comment: Good point, I've edited my answer to add information about that limitation.